# Jinja2 does not render expresion between <>

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to render this part of a template (trying to generate some c++ code)

```
{% for signal in signals -%}
   Signal<{{ signal.type }}> {{ signal.name }};
 {% endfor %}
```

and expecting to get:

```
Signal<SignalTypeVariable> SignalNameVariable;
```

but I'm getting:

```
Signal SignalNameVariable;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `signal.type` does not have a value. Make sure it exists and has a non-empty value.

Comment: I did a test with:
    Signal<{{ signal.type }}> {{ signal.type }}  {{ signal.name }};


And that rendered the signal.type  so it seems like there is something with <> or do you need space between the expressions?

Comment: Problem's description "Jinja2 does not render expresion between <>" isn't quite true: Even `<>` **themselves** are not rendered. It looks like your `jinja2.Environment` treats `<` (and `>`) specially. E.g. `<{{` and `}}>` are used for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.. I'm displaying the render in a html front end so the tags is interpreted by the browser (even though its in a "pre" tag).

When i inspect the code in debug mode the signal type is there so it should be alright to compile.